# Write a thread-safe deque in C++11 using std::atomic

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stdatomic

I need a message deque which will be read/written concurrently. Is it enough to just write

```
std::atomic<std::deque<Message>> queue;
```

Is this the same to a wrapper class which has a `std::deque<Message> queue_` and a `std::mutex mutex_` as data members, and locks `mutex_` before forwards any operation to `queue_`?

Comment: This wont work. You need to lock a mutex wherever you read/modify the data structure from different threads

Comment: You're looking for magic pixie dust that you sprinkle on your code to make it thread-safe. If you find it let me know, I have some magic beans you might want to buy.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely not.

This is hideously unsafe. The long and short is that creating safe performant concurrent data structures is unbelievably complex, and a million miles away from "Just lock a mutex every access". It would take you years or decades to create your own. The API design is completely different from a Standard container, just for starters.

You need to source these structures from a reliable source, like Intel (TBB) or Microsoft (PPL). Boost.Lockfree has some too.

Comment: Seconding DeadMG here. The TBB library is available under GPLv2 (with the linking exception) and works great on Linux, Windows, and even ARM platforms. The class you'll want is here:
http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_queue_cls.htm